# Calculating time-constant with z-Diodes

Tags: zener, time-constant

I'm a student in Computer Sciences and am currently preparing myself for an Exam in Electronics. I came across this Exercise:

[image]

(U_0(t) = 10V), u(0) = 0V)

I don't have any solutions for the exercise, which is why i'm asking here:

The exercise is to calculate the time constants as well as the end values for the capacitor-voltage ( u(t) ) in case of a charging or discharging the capacitor. It seems to be an easy task in case of the discharging: The capacitor can only apply it's voltage to R_2 because of the Diode, so tau_1 = R_2 * C. Also the end-value for the charging-procedure (for me) seems to be equal to the z-voltage.

But what about the time-constant for the charging-procedure? We're assuming, that the diode and z-diode are absolutely ideal here. So modeling the z-diode with a voltage-source and a resistor r_z of 0 Ohm would lead to a short-circuit when calculating the pre-resistor for the capacitor!

What am i missing here?

This is my first post here and i would consider myself not really experienced, so take it easy on me!

Comment: Loading procedure??? What’s that about then?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not a native speaker! What i meant is applying charge to the capacitor. If you can tell me the right word for what i wanted to say, i'll edit the question.

Comment: Don't forget that ZD is not active **until its voltage reaches 5.6V**. Above that, it seems you should assume its cathode remains at +5.6V. Below 5.6V, it is not active, and is an open circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out myself:

When the capacitor in the given example is charged, current is applied to both of the present resistors R_1 and R_2. To calculate the time-constant tau (tau = R * C), we have to first calculate the pre-resistor in front of the capacitor which in this case (not taking the diodes or voltage-sources into account) is

$$R_1||R_2 = \frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2} = \frac{33k\cdot 100k}{33k+100k} = 24.812k$$

So tau would be:

$$\tau = R \cdot C \approx 25k\Omega \cdot 8nF = 0.0002S$$

When the voltage source is detached, the capacitor itself will become a voltage source, which discharges in the direction of the Diode. No positive current will flow through the Diode, so the capacitor will apply current only to R_2. So

$$\tau_2 = R_2 \cdot C = 100k\Omega \cdot 8nF = 0.0008S$$

Answer (score 0):

The actual "r_z of the Zener" in datasheets is called **Zzt** or the impedance **Z** of the zener **z** at the **t**est current e.g. 5mA.

Since this is an "incremental" or "knee" slope on the curve above some **th**reshold voltage, V**th** which is just below the rated Vz voltage.

It includes the knee voltage in the equation **Vzt= Vth + Izt*Zzt**

**Your assumption is incorrect  as an ideal voltage source because here it is an incremental resistance only when operating in Zener mode current and not at 0V.**

It would be the same as an ideal battery except only during Charge mode.

When the input=0V , and (Vcap = +), D is no longer forward biased and blocks the zener  with open circuit

Comment: Use Google translator